# Unable to upload file in sharepoint C# code

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have below code and i want to upload a file on sharepoint site in specific folder.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using MSharp.Framework.Services;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;

namespace SharepointFileSend
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string password = "XXX!";
        private static string hostWeb = "XXX.sharepoint.com";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites"; //site on which file needs to be uploaded (don’t put / at end)
            string documentlibrary = "Documents"; //Document library where file needs to be uploaded
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("XXXX@XXX.com", securePassword);
            string sharePointDocPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), "test.html");


            byte[] binary = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sharePointDocPath);
            string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sharePointDocPath);
            string result = string.Empty;
            //Url to upload filef
            string resourceUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api", siteUrl);

            RestClient RC = new RestClient("http://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/_api");
            NetworkCredential NCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            RC.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(NCredential);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating Rest Request");
            RestRequest Request = new RestRequest("contextinfo ?$select = FormDigestValue", Method.POST);
            Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application / json; odata = verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("Body", "");

            string ReturnedStr = RC.Execute(Request).Content;
            int StartPos = ReturnedStr.IndexOf("FormDigestValue") + 18;
            int length = (ReturnedStr.IndexOf(@""",",StartPos)-StartPos);
            string FormDigestValue = ReturnedStr.Substring(StartPos, length);

            Console.WriteLine("Uploading file Site……");

            resourceUrl = string.Format("/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/Files/add(url = '{1}’,overwrite=true)", documentlibrary, fname);
            Request = new RestRequest(resourceUrl, Method.POST);
            Request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application / json; odata = verbose");
            Request.AddHeader("X - RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);
            Console.WriteLine("File is successfully uploaded to sharepoint site.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the output as :
File is successfully uploaded to sharepoint site.
But when i search the file in sharepoint ,file is not present.
Please help improving this code.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to upload a file to a subdirectory in a folder inside a document library. The code I posted uploads a binary stream to a file to a specific folder. Hope this helps.

```
 public async Task UploadToSharePoint( Stream stream, SharePointOnlineCredentials creds, string url, string folder, string fileName )
 {
      try
      {

          var clientContext = new ClientContext( url)
          {
              Credentials = creds
          };
          var web = clientContext.Web;

          // load the site lists 
          clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Lists, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl);
          await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
          //  format: /sites/SITE_NAME/LIBRARY_INTERNAL_NAME/FOLDER_NAME
          var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folder);

           clientContext.Load( folder );
           await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
           var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                Overwrite = true, 
                ContentStream = stream,
                Url = fileName
             };

           var uploadFile= folder.Files.Add( fileCreationInformation );
           clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
           await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

---